# How to get a certain subview from UIView by tag

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I'm a noob in Objective-C and I have one question.

I have one `UILabel` object that I adding to one UIView with this code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,self.view.frame.size.width-15-70, 30)];
label.tag = 1;
label.font = [PublicObject fontTexts:17];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
 view.backgroundColor = [PublicObject colorWithHexString:@"cd4110"];
 label.text = [filterData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 view addSubview:label];
```

Now I want get one subview in my view where this subview has **tag = 1** and save it on another object like this:

```
UILabel *tagLabel;
tagLabel = // I want get one subview in view where tag = 1
```

Please help me understand how to do this.

Comment: First of all, there can be many subviews with one tag. So correct question is "how to get subviews from uiview by tag".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get your subviews with for loop iteration

```
for (UIView *i in self.view.subviews){
      if([i isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            UILabel *newLbl = (UILabel *)i;
            if(newLbl.tag == 1){
                /// Write your code
            }
      }
}
```

**Swift**

```
let label:UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
```

Comment: my friend I want get UILabel with tag!!! if were many label in my view I can't use this ... please guide me with tag for any label

Comment: Set the unique tag values to all views and access the object using tag.

Comment: Fastest code is not taht but it is that:
UILabel *tagLabel =  (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:1];

Comment: [view viewWithTag:x] also searches hierarchically, not just the immediate children. If you want to avoid searching subviews of subviews this might be a good answer, but that's kind of a niche use case. Or if you want to avoid finding matching tags that aren't UILabel at all cost, then this manual approach might also be called for.

Comment: Use [UIView viewWithTag:]

Answer (score 80):

Example with `UILabel`:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

good luck!

Answer (score 30):

You can get the subview with the code which others have mentioned, just like

```
UILabel *tagLabel = (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:1];
```

But an important point to remember,

- Make sure the parent view doesn't have the same tag value as of the subview. Otherwise the `viewWithTag:` method will return the receiver view (on which you are calling `viewWithTag:`) instead of returning the actual subview you want.

So keep the parent view and child views tags distinct whenever you need to use `viewWithTag:`.

Comment: MAKE SURE YOUR PARENT VIEW DOES NOT HAVE THE SAME TAG AS YOUR PARENT VIEW !!! I was on the verge of losing my mind.  Thank You.  Your comment saved my life.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3, Swift 4 and Swift 5**

```swift
if let subLabel: UILabel = primaryView.viewWithTag(123) as? UILabel {
    subLabel.text = "do things here :-D"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [viewWithTag:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag%3a) method.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on the same view

```
UILabel *tagLabel =  (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:1];
```

Also, if you want a new instance of UILabel

```
UILabel *newTagLabel = [tagLabel copy];
//customize new label here...
[view addSubView:newTagLabel];
```