# Get UITextField from UIView using an Identifier/Tag (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield

I need to know how I can access a particular UITextField within a UIView from the ViewController class.

The setup I have currently is that I have ViewController that is linked to a View in Storyboard. I have UIView in nib that has 3 UITextFields. I load the view up using the following code:

```
TextFieldView = UINib(nibName: "TextView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
self.view.addSubview(TextFieldView)
```

I can get all three UITextField and their values using the following code:

```
for case let textField as UITextField in TextView!.subviews {
    print(textField.text)
}
```

My issue is that how can I get the value of any one particular UITextField using some sort of identifier or a tag. Lets say I have 3 UITextFields named TextField1, TextField2, and TextField3 respectively. How do I get the value of TextField2?

Comment: duplicated： http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530459/how-to-get-certain-subview-from-uiview-by-tag

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to find it by class then you can loop like as :

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if let textField = view as? UITextField {
        print(textField.text!)
    }
}
```

If you want to find through tag then you can use `viewWithTag` as described by @BalajiKondalrayal.

Set tag of text field as follows :

[image]

Select text field and set tag property.

```
@IBAction func getAllTextFromTextFields(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Get All Values
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if let textField = view as? UITextField {
            print(textField.text!)
        }
    }
    //Get One By One with Tag
    if let txtField1 = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField {
        print(txtField1.text!)
    }

}
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: I have this code currently, I need to use the viewWithTag but I don't know how to set the tag of a particular UITextField in a nib

Comment: Thank you, I just got it right before you posted the answer but because of your effort I gave you the check mark. I appreciate the time you have taken in solving my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use viewWithTag option.
Try this:

```
if let theTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(yourTagId) as? UITextField {
        print(theTextField.text)
    }
```

Objective-C :

```
UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:YourTagId];

if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]
{ NSLog(@"%@", view.text);
}
```

Comment: how do I set a tag of a UITextField inside a nib?

Comment: can you convert this to Objective C?

Comment: In your objective c code, it should be 
```[self.view viewWithTag:YourTagId]; ```
instead of 
```[self.view.viewWithTag:YourTagId];```