# Get Identifier and Hint of UIView in swift class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, identifier

I'm assigning an identifier to a view using storyboard and want to access it through swift class. Is there any method to do that? I'm searching it on stackoverflow but couldn't find any solution.

Few people gave [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967735/get-uitextfield-from-uiview-using-an-identifier-tag-swift) to use tag instead of identifier but I want to ask that isn't there any solution to get these hints and identifiers inside of swift class.

[image]

it gives error when ever I try to access it using `accessibilityIdentifier`.

[image]

Comment: `print(myView.accessibilityIdentifier)` - you get identifier. `print(myView.accessibilityHint)` - you get your hint. Or do you need something else? then the question is not entirely clear.

Comment: @VadimNikolaev I've updated my question. I'm trying to access it using accessibilityIdentifier but it gives me error.

Comment: Sure, you have to do something in your code with this property `view.accessibilityIdentifier` (for example, just print it) and the error will disappear

Comment: Thanks! now it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access it via `accessibilityIdentifier` e.g. `myView.accessibilityIdentifier`

Comment: This is not working for me. is it working inside of your code?

Comment: As Keshu already stated, you need to assign it to a variable or use it directly in an `if` or `switch` statement:
```if view.accessibilityIdentifier == "phoneTF" { // do something }```
or ```switch(view.accessibilityIdentifier) { case "phoneTF": // do something default: // do somthing else }```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are not using the value. Just assign it to a variable an it will work.

```
let yourId = yourView.accessibilityIdentifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension

```
var viewIdentifier: String?{
    get {
        return self.accessibilityIdentifier
    }
    set {
        self.accessibilityIdentifier = newValue
    }
}
```